Bootstrap5 div class oddity
I have some simple html w/ php code but in VSCode i'm getting an error marker in the following..
enter image description here
Why the "red" error indicator on the closing quite for the first div, but second div is fine?
Writing code in VSCode...

Please include a minimal reproducible example and show us your code using code blocks. We need to try your code out to see the problem.

Your <form> tag is incomplete.
Look:
<form class="row g-3" action="create.php" method="POST>
-----------------------------------------------------^

It's missing a ".
